# How to troubleshoot suspend and hibernate in Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-10.04, hibernate, suspend, panasonic-toughbook

I have Ubuntu Lucid installed on a Panasonic Toughbook CF-29.  Most things work well, but, under Gnome, suspend and hibernate do not work.  Interestingly, in Xubuntu, hibernate does work.  So my question is twofold:

1) How do I troubleshoot the hibernate function in Gnome desktop (since I know the laptop can hibernate in Ubuntu), and

2) How to go about troubleshooting the suspend function?  I got as far as looking at the /var/log/pm-suspend.log, but that just tells me the things that ran successfully... I'm kind of stuck there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Some tips are at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspendHibernateResume

## Fails to suspend/hibernate

```
$ dmesg|less
```

There is usually an entry what application caused the suspension to fail:

```
[32467.560058] Freezing of tasks failed after 20.01 seconds (1 tasks refusing to freeze, wq_busy=0):
[32467.560115] plasma-desktop D 0000000000000000 0 2065 1 0x00800004
...
```

The stack trace often tells you where the problem might lie:

```
[32467.560155] [<ffffffff81087f00>] ? autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x40
[32467.560163] [<ffffffffa016e523>] SendReceive+0x1a3/0x3b0 [cifs]
[32467.560169] [<ffffffffa0153c79>] CIFSSMBUnixQPathInfo+0x139/0x2b0 [cifs]
[32467.560176] [<ffffffffa016853d>] cifs_get_inode_info_unix+0x7d/0x1a0
```

- here it is the [CIFS (samba) mounts](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/752012).

## Fail to resume

Make sure the swap partition is correctly set, see https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq

Comment: Great link - I hadn't actually seen that one yet.  AFAIC, this answer is the best answer to date to my question ("how to troubleshoot"...) so I'm awarding the bounty here.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have Ubuntu hibernation issue on laptop as well as desktops. Then I read somewhere, and which made sense, was that the swap space must be big enough to store the current memory contents. So a good rule of thumb is to have a swap space slightly bigger than the physical memory the laptop has.

So I used 1.6GB of swap for 1GB memory in the next Ubuntu release installation (I am now on Ubuntu 10.04) and I can hibernate the laptop without any issue.

Another way to make it work is to use swap file and not swap partition. Below link has more details:

[Hybernate without partition](https://superuser.com/questions/21020/can-i-hibernate-linux-without-a-swap-partition)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what exactly the issue is. I would start by carefully examining the `pm-suspend.log`

I found the page on Debian website more helpful than the one on the Ubuntu site as far as suspend troubleshooting goes: https://wiki.debian.org/Suspend

In my case 1 out of every few suspends causes the system to freeze (not going in suspend). From the pm-suspend.log, I found that the issue has to do with the video card driver:

Successful suspend message:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
kernel.acpi_video_flags = 0
/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend: success.
```

Failed suspend messages:

```
Running hook /usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/99video suspend suspend:
```

And then nothing, this is where it hangs.

The next step is to enable debugging by inserting line export `PM_DEBUG=true` into the beginning of file `/usr/lib/pm-utils/pm-functions`.
After I did this, I found that it hung at `chvt 63` and I found a bug report that eventually made me install the Proprietary video driver from the manufacturer.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Ubuntu has a problem with suspend and hibernate on laptops.

See this Ubuntu Forums HowTo : [Fix suspend and hibernate on laptops](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=471855).
This article has many comments that might be worthwhile reading.

Comment: Hmm... I've looked at a bunch of stuff like this.  Mostly what I've seen are "shotgun" solutions (like "try uswsusp").  My question is really more "how to troubleshoot".  I'm looking for a linux guru who is familiar with these components in the different variants of Ubuntu to give some pointers as to how to figure it out, not just go down a long list of things to try to see if they work.

Comment: As the problem seems to be localized to the Ubuntu distribution and only on laptops, you might be better asking it in their forums. As a last note, the following threads contain lots of pointers and info : [Troubleshooting suspend and hibernate](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1144999) and [How to troubleshoot Suspend/Hibernate in Ubuntu 10.10](http://www.baudlabs.com/archives/1287).

Comment: funny - it worked fine for me on my netbook :)

Comment: @warren: Apparently, the problem is not for all models.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](https://01.org/blogs/rzhang/2015/best-practice-debug-linux-suspend/hibernate-issues) on 01.org provides information on debugging Linux Suspend/Hibernate issues:

- Introduces some common debug methods.
- Introduces some typical issues that can break Linux suspend/hibernate.
- Gives step-by-step instructions based on different symptoms of the problem.