# How much swap space needed for 4GB RAM

Tags: linux, memory, swap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Swap partition size for 4GB RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/16280/swap-partition-size-for-4gb-ram)

For 4GB RAM how much swap space needed ?

If I made 8GB as swap space, weather my system become slow ? If so then what is the reason for that?

In 4GB RAM how many addressing is possible? how its is related to 32 bit and 64 bit system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been [answered before](https://superuser.com/q/16280/13559).

Do you want to be able to hibernate the machine? Then at least as much swap as RAM. If you only suspend, or won't bother to hibernate, you can get away with only 2GB swap.

If you use many RAM-heavy applications, like virtualizing machines and stream encoding, you may want more swap, but for the average user, matching your RAM is adequate.

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to have an equal amount of swap space as you do RAM. You can feel free to assign 8GB if you wish; however, this is not as applicable today as it was in the past when RAM was more expensive and some processes ran in swap space.

In 4GB there is 2^32 bytes which is 4,294,967,296. Anymore than that and a 32-bit system will not be able to address the memory.